# How do I set a div's height based on the child's width?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, an inner and outer, and the inner is an absolutely positioned child of the outer. I would like that when the inner div's width changes, the outer div's height (not width), change to match. I have prepared a simple fiddle here to properly explain what I am looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/2GTDd/5/

The width of the inner div in this case is fixed at 200px, and so is the height of the outer. Is there anyway that the width of the inner div be dynamic (based on the content), and the height of the outer increase automatically to match? I can solve this with JS easily, but I would like to see if there is a non-JS solution first.

The code in the  fiddle:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#outer {
    width: 100px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}
#inner {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: so you are looking for a pure CSS solution?

Comment: @Zword Yes, but there is no need to support IE9 or lower, so a CSS3 solution would be ideal

Comment: I will try to find a solution.Check for an answer later

Comment: This is so easy with jQuery, any reason you can't use JS?

Comment: @Wezly I don't like to use JS if a non-JS solution is available. I am aware a simple `$("#outer").height($("#inner").width());` will solve my problem, and I was also curious if it could be done with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below solution:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GTDd/11/)

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
}
#inner {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

---

## ***Update:***

Since the div was rotated from the center thats why my CSS wasnt giving exact output.So I just set the `transform-origin:0 0;` CSS which will rotate div from left instead of from the center:

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GTDd/18/)

Comment: It's funny, the entire reason I posted my question was to achieve rotation, and have a place for the rotated element to fit without stepping over other elements. I think your solution will point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Ermir check my updated answer(Fiddle at the bottom of the answer)

Comment: It presented a viable solution to the problem I was having. With some modifications, it is the correct answer. I will implement it tonight when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS3 rotation, have a look at this <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/2GTDd/15/)</kbd>.

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#inner {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#outer {
    width: 100px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}
#inner {
    width:200px;
    height:inherit;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2GTDd/7/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the full solutions of your problem.
But, I hope this example brings you a litte bit forward.
Its an example of height equals width (or every other aspect ratio) in pure CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/2GTDd/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="box ratio1_2">
            <div class="content">Aspect ratio of <span>1:2</span></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .ratio1_2:before {
    padding-top: 200%;
}
.box:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 5% 5% 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
}

.content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
}
.content span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use hieght auto for your outer div

Comment: Not sure that you read the question, or saw the fiddle - `height:auto` will not set the outer div's `height` to the inner divs `width`

Comment: Because the outer div has only absolutely positioned elements inside, `height: auto;` will give it a height of 0. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Well i was using my phone so couldnt see fiddle are u expecting pure css solution?